# What Material for reflective surface of a solar grill/barbecue?

Tags: optics, temperature, reflection, material-science

I have been planning on building a solar grill for quite a time now, and the one problem, which is also the biggest - I need to shape a mirror into a paraboloid, so it bundles solar energy efficiently.

My designs for the whole thing have the focal area of the paraboloid - i.e. the grillage - placed in close proximity of the mirror, depending on the design between 1 and 1.20 meters.

I am afraid that the heat radiating from the focal area would heat up the reflective surface too much, especially if I use an easy-to-shape material like acrylic mirror, which would without a doubt deform after a couple of minutes.

So long story short, I want to know if there is a material that

1. Has high reflective properties
2. Does not deform at temperatures of 300°C or even higher (400°C to be on the safe side, if the BBQ is going on for hours and to calculate in unexpected risks)
3. Is reasonably easy to shape (it should be possible without having to handle gigantic machinery or overly dangerous tools)
4. Can be paid for by a poor engineering-student, so the amount I need should be below 200$. If possible. (a griller is pointless if I have to eat rice for the rest of the year)

Ps.: English is not my first language, so there likely are a lot of mistakes in there. If something is unclear, please comment! I apologize for those mistakes beforehand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Circular disk of of (soft) aluminum shim, hydroform it into a spherical cap (good enough); deform that into a parabola.  Polish the inside (paint the outside black).  Or, glue smoothed aluminum foil to an old satellite dish.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/380546818446?lpid=82

When somebody says "renewable, sustainable, environmentally sound," see where *they* eat dinner.